# Black Screen When Initially Booting

Tags: boot, screen, 15.04

This is my first time ever installing a Linux OS. I installed 15.04 using a DVD, when the installation was dome I had to restart the computer (I did an install that erased everything else). When i restart I get a magenta screen (with no Ubuntu logo) and then I turns black. My mouse shows up but nothing else. I also tried installing 14.04 (erasing everything else) and it had the same problem. I can't access the grub, I've already tried. I also tried doing the nomodeset before installing and I still got the black screen, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Being that you installed via DVD I can only help but wonder, was your original OS Windows 8+?
If so you may just be encountering the common boot loader error.

Try this:

1. Restart your computer
2. Press F2 (or whatever F key your manufactured designated) to load up the BIOS setup
3. Navigate to the 'Security' Section and change 'Secure Boot' to Disabled
4. Navigate to the 'Boot' Section and change the 'Boot Mode' to CSM (or BIOS/Legacy depending on your manufacturer)
5. Finally press F10 (or whatever F key your manufacturer designated) to 'Exit Saving Changes'

This should work. If you still experience the Black screen try one last time to reinstall Ubuntu to ensure that everything is correctly installed.

Hope this answer helped :)